# Display remaining time in playlist in VLC

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, playlists

Is there any way to display the remaining time in the current playlist in VLC? Right now I can see the total time of the playlist:

[image]

and the remaining time for the current video:

[image]

but I didn't find the display the remaining time in the current playlist (= sum of lengths of all the remaining tracks in the playlists).

I use the latest version of VLC (2.1.3) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I too would love to display the remaining time in the current playlist in VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Playlist does not keep that info (see [wiki.videolan.org/Playlist](https://wiki.videolan.org/Playlist/) but you can display the remaining time in the current song/video by clicking on the display time [wiki.videolan.org/Qt_Interface/#Time_label](https://wiki.videolan.org/Qt_Interface/#Time_label).

More about VLC Playlists see [wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Playlist](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Playlist/)